# C++ Random Number Generation

Tags: c++, random

I am making a few wrapper classes for the C++ standard library and was wondering if the following code is good practice.

```
#pragma once

#include <random>

namespace LibraryName
{
    class RandomBase
    {
    protected:
        RandomBase()
            : m_RandomGenerator(m_RandomDevice()) {}

        std::random_device m_RandomDevice;
        std::mt19937 m_RandomGenerator;
    };

    template<typename T>
    class IntRandom : public RandomBase
    {
    public:
        IntRandom(T minValue, T maxValue)
            : m_Distribution(minValue, maxValue), m_MinValue(minValue), m_MaxValue(maxValue) {}

        T Next()
        {
            return m_Distribution(m_RandomGenerator);
        }

        inline T GetMinValue() const { return m_MinValue; }
        inline T GetMaxValue() const { return m_MaxValue; }

    private:
        std::uniform_int_distribution<T> m_Distribution;
        T m_MinValue;
        T m_MaxValue;
    };

    template<typename T>
    class FloatRandom : public RandomBase
    {
    public:
        FloatRandom(T minValue, T maxValue)
            : m_Distribution(minValue, maxValue), m_MinValue(minValue), m_MaxValue(maxValue) {}

        T Next()
        {
            return m_Distribution(m_RandomGenerator);
        }

        inline T GetMinValue() const { return m_MinValue; }
        inline T GetMaxValue() const { return m_MaxValue; }

    private:
        std::uniform_real_distribution<T> m_Distribution;
        T m_MinValue;
        T m_MaxValue;
    };

    class BoolRandom : public RandomBase
    {
    public:
        BoolRandom() : BoolRandom(0.5f) {}
        BoolRandom(float trueChance)
            : m_Distribution(trueChance), m_TrueChance(trueChance) {}

        bool Next()
        {
            return m_Distribution(m_RandomGenerator);
        }

        inline bool GetTrueChance() const { return m_TrueChance; }

    private:
        std::bernoulli_distribution m_Distribution;
        float m_TrueChance;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That seems like a lot of code for very little purpose. It's allowing you to write

```
IntRandom<int> r(17, 42);
int i = r.Next();
```

instead of the no-helpers version,

```
std::mt19937 g(std::random_device{}());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(17, 42);
int i = dist(g);
```

Some people would say that that's not worth the 77 lines of code.

---

Two small problems with your code, related to your use of `random_device`: First, you're using only 32 bits of entropy to seed your entire Mersenne Twister; it would be better to use as many bits as the `mt19937` has bits of state. However, doing this correctly is [needlessly difficult](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0205r0.html) in C++17, so you get a pass on it for now.

Second, your `RandomBase` class keeps a *member* of type `random_device`. This might be problematic, because a `random_device` is essentially an open file handle to `/dev/urandom`. If you create a lot of `RandomBase` objects at once, you might find yourself running out of file handles.

Oh, and a third problem is that `random_device` is non-copyable and non-movable; so your `RandomBase` is also non-movable. That could actually be pretty bad, depending on how you want to use it.

---

You could fix the `random_device` issues by removing the `random_device` data member, and instead providing a method like this:

```
void RandomBase::reseed() {
    std::random_device rd;
    m_RandomGenerator.seed(rd());  // TODO: better seeding
}
```

This keeps the `random_device` alive (and `/dev/urandom` open) only as long as it's needed; and it removes the data member from the class so that the class becomes movable and even copyable.

---

You could also reduce duplication by using templates and type-aliases, something like this:

```
template<class Distribution>
class dist_and_gen {
    std::mt19937 m_g;
    Distribution m_dist;

    template<class... Args>
    explicit constexpr dist_and_gen(Args&&...) :
        m_dist(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    auto next() { return m_dist(m_g); }
    auto params() const { return m_dist.params(); }
};

template<class T> using IntRandom =
    dist_and_gen<std::uniform_int_distribution<T>>;
template<class T> using FloatRandom =
    dist_and_gen<std::uniform_float_distribution<T>>;
template<class T> using BoolRandom =
    dist_and_gen<std::bernoulli_distribution<T>>;
```

This version loses some of the details, such as your custom-named accessors for the parameters; but it preserves a lot of the details "accidentally". For example, I didn't try to preserve your `BoolRandom::BoolRandom()` default constructor; but it turns out that [it just works](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/bernoulli_distribution/bernoulli_distribution) anyway, thanks to the default constructor of the standard `bernoulli_distribution`.

Comment: Would [PCG](http://www.pcg-random.org/) be a better choice when in need of randomness?

Comment: @yuri, I don't have experience in the area, but IIRC if the predefined random number generators are seeded well, they should be equivalent in numbers they produce. Just make to sure to seed with current time in nanoseconds, `std::random_device{}()`, and some number of your choice. That should avoid nasty behavior of mingw producing the same number all the time when `std::random_device{}()` is used. The approach requires use of `std::seed_seq`, which for unknown reasons is terribly hard to use.

Answer (score 1):

I basically wrote the same helper classes for my work. The advantage of them is twofold

1. It allows reproduction of noisy simulations by defining a seed
2. Normally random number generators are rather costly in their initialization but cheap in returning the next value. So regarding @Quuxplusone there is a major performance difference between

   ```
   IntRandom<int> r(17, 42);
   for (size_t i=0; i < something large; ++i)
       int i = r.Next();
   ```

   Compared to

   ```
   for (size_t i=0; i < something large; ++i){
       std::mt19937 g(std::random_device{}());
       std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(17, 42);
       int i = dist(g);
   }
   ```

   Also embedding them into your class is much easier with a given interface.

Now for the actual review. I think your base class lacks one key feature and that is passage of a seed. Also the random_device is unnecessary as @Quuxplusone pointed out, so reduce this to:

```
class RandomBase
{
protected:
    RandomBase() 
        : RandomDevice(std::mt19937(std::random_device()))
    {}

    RandomBase(const double seed) 
        : RandomDevice(std::mt19937(seed))
    {}
    std::mt19937 m_RandomGenerator;
};
```

Regarding your IntDistribution I would say it has a bad name and it is way overcomplicated. On one hand there is the member function `std::uniform_int_distribution::max` which does what your `GetMaxValue` does. Also i do not really see a benefit in it beeing a template class so I would reduce it to:

```
class RandomUniformInt : public RandomBase {
public:
    RandomUniformInt (int lower_bound, int upper_bound)
        : dist(lower_bound, upper_bound) 
    {}
    RandomUniformInt(int lower_bound, int upper_bound, double seed)
        : RandomBase(seed)
        , dist(lower_bound, upper_bound) 
    {}

    int operator ()() { return dist(m_RandomGenerator); }
private:
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist;
};
```

That said given the minimal impact of RadomBase I would actually inline it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason the class is a template is so that IntRandom can be used for other types of integer (short, long, etc).

Comment: I wouldn't suggest re-seeding your PRNG each time through the loop! That *would* be obviously bad. But you could do `std::mt19937 g(...); for (size_t i=0; i < something large; ++i) { int i = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(17, 42)(g); }` and pay no performance penalty at all for doing so.

Comment: True but if you want to embed it somewhere such a simple convenience class is much better than writing it out